# How to store chat history for recall?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

I had a very fun interaction today using the math chat to ask an open ended question that I wanted to think more about, but wouldn't be comfortable asking in the normal Q/A (since I think its not quite up to the standards).

I would like some mechanism to stores these conversations so I can revisit them later.

Is there an official functionality for that?

Comment: Yes that's possible. In a chat room click "room" and then "create new bookmark". I am not an expert on  that feature. But at least one frequent meta user uses it frequently. So you might get more info soon.

Comment: @quid I wonder who you meant by *frequent meta user*. At the moment I'll add at least some links: [How to bookmark a conversation?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/how-to-bookmark-a-conversation). These question are about somewhat different topic, but they at least contain some screenshots which might be helpful: [Is it possible to bookmark a conversation in chat, which has messages in two different days?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160767) and [Take selected parts of a conversation and bookmark it in Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115689)

Comment: If by *store* you meant store locally (on your computer), that's a bit different. There is this feature request: [Allow to save a chat conversation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102015). But you can simply copy/paste the text or do something similar. You can find a bit more about this topic if you browse Meta.SE questions tagged [chat-bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat-bookmarks) or [conversation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversation). When I have a bit more time, I might come back and expand these comments to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to store a conversation from chat locally on your own computer, then you can use whatever you would do with some other website. (Copy-paste text, print as pdf, save as html, etc.)  As far as I know, there is (so far) no special feature to *export* some chat messages.

If you want some kind of bookmark to some conversation in chat, than this is exactly what [chat bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/chat-bookmarks/info) are for.

Details can be found, for example, here:

- [How can I bookmark a chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117569)
- [Can I share a link to a specific message? Or range of messages?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#permalink) in [chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq).

What you do is that you either click "bookmark a conversation" button in the transcript.

[image: screenshot]

Or if you are present in a chatroom then you can find this in the dropdown menu on the right.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Then you simply follow the instructions. You select the first message of the conversation. Then you move to find the last message you want to be part of your conversation and click on it.

What you achieve by this is that the particular conversation appears in two places. One is conversation tab of that specific room. (Here is the [conversation tab of Mathematics chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics?tab=conversations).) And it also appears in your chat profile among conversations. (I will use [my own profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/11287/martin-sleziak?tab=conversations) as an example.)

Some useful things to keep in mind:

- The conversation tab is a shared resource for all users of the chatroom. So you should keep this in mind and not use all space there for yourself. (But if you do not bookmark something too often, you're probably fine. And, of course, this is a non-issue for a room which is used only by a few users.)
- You can also remove the conversation. If you delete a conversation and then create a conversation in the same room with exactly the same name, the url will also be the same. (This is useful if you want to keep the same link - for example if you already linked to the conversation from elsewhere - but you want to add more messages.)
- If you post a link to conversation as a chat message, it is [oneboxed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/onebox/info).